# How to get comment from facebook comment plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I followed this guide to trigger a function when a comment is made. I am currently able to make an ajax call to interact with my DB when a comment is made.

[FB Comments Plugin - Detect comment on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773800/fb-comments-plugin-detect-comment-on-page)

What i want to do is save a copy of the comment in my own DB each time a comment is made. Im not sure i want to use facebook comments forever so id like to have all the data saved in my DB incase i revert to the original comment system i had.

Ive tried using jquery to get the value from the textbox and the username from the span.

```
var comment = $('.mentionsTextarea').val();
var username = $('.commentasName').html();
```

This code does not get the data. Im guessing its because its inside an iframe. Im wondering if its possible to get the data from the actual object when the comment commit is triggered. So when the event is triggered i can get the data from the comment object? Something like this.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function(response) {
    var comment = comment.text();
    var username = comment.username.text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the answer i wanted, but i do have a solution to this. This will get the latest comment made for a particular url.

```
$comments = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids='.$url);
$comments = json_decode($comments, true);
$comments = $comments[$url]['comments']['data'];
$latestComment = $comments[0];
$username = $latestComment['from']['name'];
$message = $latestComment['message'];
echo $username ." - ".$message;
```